# Rails devise add management routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am not to sure what the best way, but in a way i am kinda mixing up myself. What i am trying to do is a way for an admin to go into a user profile and modify items.

Route

```
  devise_for :customers, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
  resources :usermanagements
```

Controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    @customer = Customer.find(current_customer.id)
    if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the customer bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @customer, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@customer)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def edit
   @customer = current_customer
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class UsermanagementsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @usermngmts = Customer.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
  end
  def show
    @usermngmts = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Views registration/edit.html.erb

```
# i am trying to designate this one for public view
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put })  do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

This works

Views
usermanagements/index.html.erb

```
<% @usermngmts.each do |usrmngmt| %>
    <%= usrmngmt.incomplete_name %>
    <%= link_to ... i would like to go to the edit of usermanagement controller but get usermngents/userid/edit %>
    </div>
<% end%>
```

What the best approach to not mix those two controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do, but if you wanted to provide a separate controller for an admin to be able to manage registrations (or customers), you could always create an "admin" namespace, and then use admin/registrations and admin/customers controllers to provide customized routes and actions, with access limited to administrators.

More info on namespaces here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing